# Displaying junk characters in case of Arabic in PDF Generated by itextpdf-5.5.13.1

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to update a PDF using the existing PDF with some values from another service and one of the fields may have arabic words in it. In case of english everything works fine but in case of arabic final pdf is displaying the junk characters.

Below is snippet:

```
public  String  processPDF(String src, String dest,Map<String,String> paramMap)
    {
        String base64PdfString = "";

        try {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
        PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);

        String beneficiaryName =  "سامي جافيد";//paramMap.get("beneficiaryName");

        if (object instanceof PRStream) 
        {
            PRStream stream = (PRStream)object;
            byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
            String dd = new String(data);
            dd = dd.replace("$HeaderBeneficiary","Beneficiary");
            dd = dd.replace("$HeaderDate","Date");
            dd = dd.replace("$HeaderAmount","Amount");
            if(textContainsArabic(beneficiaryName)) {
                dd = dd.replace("$BeneficiaryName",BidiLine.processLTR(beneficiaryName,1,1));
            }
            else
            {
                dd = dd.replace("$BeneficiaryName",beneficiaryName);
            }
        stream.setData(dd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();

        GeneratePDFFromTemplate generatePdf = new GeneratePDFFromTemplate();
        base64PdfString = generatePdf.convertPdfToBase64(dest);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Failed to generate PDF Document");
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return base64PdfString;
        }
```

textContainsArabic is a method that tells if string has arabic characters or not and convertPdfToBase64 converts the file into base64.

Comment: Your PDF editing mechanism only works for very simple PDFs and replacements. In particular you shouldn't assume that any replacements outside the **WinAnsiEncoding** range (essentially only the glyphs common in Western European languages), even if the PDFs are simple enough.

Comment: PDF is really very simple and most of the fields are numbers and dates except this name field which should accept the arabic as well. I have tried using ISO-8859-6 & UTF-8 encoding as well it changed the characters but not the actual arabic characters.

Comment: As said above, don't expect your code to work with Arabic replacement texts. You are lucky if it works for Western European ("English" as you said) characters.

Comment: There should be some way to display arabic text. Can you please point out problems in the code or refer any documentation to display arabic texts?

Comment: Yes, of course one can display Arabic text. But you cannot simply do some text replacement in a stream of instructions without rhyme or reason. You don't share your PDF, so I have to guess. What I assume, is that the text you want to replace is written in some font with **WinAnsiEncoding** or something similar. So by simple replacement you simply cannot get Arabic characters because they don't exist in that encoding. Instead you have to remove the original placeholder and add, at the same page position, using a different font with an encoding which includes Arabic characters, the replacement.

Comment: I have tried adding a new field as well but didn't get Arabic in the output file. May be I am not following the right tutorial to do so :-)